# Adding scroll bars in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Have successfully used a script in this site to add an independent window. It has no scroll bars. How do I add them. The script is:

```
<a href="#"
onClick="window.open(
  'popup.php?message=<?php echo $Url; ?>',
  'myWindow', 
  'status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0'
)"
class="bstyle">
  E
</a>
```

Would be grateful if you can help.
Regards
Alan Brown

Comment: There is no PHP here, you are using javascript. Edit: NVM, the question was edited to reflect the proper tags and title.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `scrollbars = 1` to the third parameter of `window.open`:

```
<a href="#"
onClick="window.open(
  'popup.php?message=<?php echo $Url; ?>',
  'myWindow', 
  'status = 1, height = 350, width = 1022, resizable = 0, scrollbars = 1'
)"
class="bstyle">
  E
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `scrollbars=1` in call

`<a href="#"
onClick="window.open('popup.php?message=<?php echo $Url; ?>', 'myWindow', 'status=1,height=350,width=1022,resizable=0,scrollbars=1'
)" class="bstyle">E</a>`